# routing in cakephp 2.1.1 like facebook

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I need to have a functionality in my site like the facebook opens the the user's profile (i.e. www.facebook.com/avadhesh.mishra). I want to have url like **www.mysite.com/username** which will open the profile of my user,

For this I added the following line in my router file but it doesn't help anymore.

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view_profile'));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code at the end of all the routs & make sure that your view_profile redirects to 404 page when the user not found.

Comment: thanks Praveen. I used Router::connect('/:usrname',array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view_user_profile'),array('pass' => array('usrname'))); which is perfectly working but I wonder why my session is not working in view while session is existing in controller. any idea?